# reduce docker build time for react static app

Tags: image, docker, docker-image

I trying to reduce the time take to build a docker image to react app,
the react should be static without server rendering.

now it takes around 5-10 minute to create an image and the image size on the local machine is around 1.5GB !!, the issue is that also after the second time of image creation, even I changed smth in the code  it doesn't use any cache
I am looking for a solution to cut the time the size  and here is my docker File after lot of changes

```
# Producation and dev build 

FROM node:14.2.0-alpine3.10 AS test1
RUN apk update
RUN apk add \
        build-base \
        libtool \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        jq \
        openssh \
        libexecinfo-dev


ADD package.json package-lock.json /app/

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

ADD . /app/

RUN rm -rf node_modules

RUN npm install --production

# copy production node_modules aside, to prevent collecting them
RUN cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules

# install ALL node_modules, including 'devDependencies'
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
RUN npm run build

RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN cp -R prod_node_modules node_modules
 
#FROM node:13.14.0
FROM test1

# copy app sources
COPY --from=test1 /app/build .
COPY --from=test1 /app/env-config.js .

# serve is what we use to run the web application
RUN npm install -g serve
# remove the sources & other needless stuff
RUN rm -rf ./src
RUN rm -rf ./prod_node_modules

# Add bash
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "serve -s build"]
```

Comment: You are using this image on prod / dev / local? If on local, then use volumes instead.

Comment: production and dev . for production is ok to wait for vut for dev is has to be changed,  what doe is mean use volume ? how ?   thanks @aryanveer

Comment: You are creating 2 images in one Dockerfile. That will create everything from scratch. What you can do is create a base image of your own in which you install all requirements. And using that image create another one which will contain your project.

Answer (score 3):

You're hitting two basic dynamics here.  The first is that your image contains a pretty large amount of build-time content, including at least some parts of a C toolchain; since your run-time "stage" is built `FROM` the build stage as is, it brings all of the build toolchain along with it.  The second is that each `RUN` command produces a new Docker layer with differences from the previous layer, so `RUN` commands only make the container larger.  More specifically `RUN rm -rf ...` makes the image slightly *larger* and does not result in space savings.

You can use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to improve this.  Each `FROM` line causes `docker build` to start over from some specified base image, and you can `COPY --from=...` previous build stages.  I'd do this in two stages, a first stage that builds the application and a second stage that runs it.

```sh
# Build stage:
FROM node:14.2.0-alpine3.10 AS build

# Install OS-level dependencies (including C toolchain)
RUN apk update \
 && apk add \
        build-base \
        libtool \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        jq \
        openssh \
        libexecinfo-dev

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install app dependencies
# (copy _just_ the package.json here so Docker layer caching works)
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# build the application
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# Final stage:
FROM node:14.2.0-alpine3.10

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --production

# get the build tree
COPY --from=build /app/build/ ./build/

# explain how to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["npx"]
CMD ["serve", "-g", "build"]
```

Note that when we get to the second stage, we run `npm install --production` on a clean Node installation; we don't try to shuffle back and forth between dev and prod dependencies.  Rather than trying to `RUN rm -rf src`, we just don't `COPY` it into the final image.

This also requires making sure you have a `.dockerignore` file that contains `node_modules` (which will reduce build times and avoid some potential conflicts; `RUN npm install` will recreate it in the directory).  If you need `react-scripts` or `serve` those should be listed in your `package.json` file.

Comment: thx , i got the following error

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-jq@1.11.1 postinstall: `npm run install-binary`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-jq@1.11.1 postinstall script.


Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -fi
/bin/sh: autoreconf: not found


    at /app/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)

Comment: Do your production dependencies need something with a C extension?  In that case you would need a third stage, that runs the `apk add ...` commands to install the build dependencies and then `npm install --production`, and the final stage can `COPY` the `node_modules` directory from that stage.

Comment: ---- thanks I had node-jq and I removed it  


I am trying to install Bash

I added  before the CMD command. the follwing: 
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

RUN chmod +x env.sh

and i got

./env.sh: line 28: .env: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: serve: command not found

Comment: also got 

ERROR: Unknown or unexpected option: -g. (on the serve g  command)